# How can I switch menus after a user logs in

Tags: theming

I'm trying to create a register/login links in the format "Register or Login" which is display for anonymous users and switched out with the user menu when a user is logged in.

I know I can preprocess those links as variables in template.php but am not sure how to access the user menu from template.php in order to write an if statement.

Ultimately, if I could do something like Forrst (images below), then tahts what I would love to end up with, but for now just trying to keep it sweet and simple.

From This:

[image]

To This after login:

[image]

Comment: To be more clear... Let's say when you are anonymous user you are displaying "Register" & "Login" links what links you want to display once the user logs in ? My Account & ??

Comment: Anything in the User Menu, which at the moment is My Account, My Public Profile, Logout.  They are styled as a horizontal bar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create the menu using UI at *admin/structure/menu*, control menu visibility by using [Menu Per Role](http://www.drupal.org/project/menu_per_role) module and then style it with CSS to get this to work.

Menu Per Role module features:

> This module allows you to restrict access to menu items based on user roles. It depends on the Drupal core menu.module—just activate both modules and edit a menu item as usual. There will be a new fieldset that allows you to restrict access by role. The fieldset also appears in the node edit form.

Screenshot of the settings which you get on menu create/edit form:

[image: snap]

Also to create the dropdown menu you could use [DHTML Menu](http://drupal.org/project/dhtml_menu) module, or [Superfish](http://drupal.org/project/superfish) module.

Comment: Thanks! One day I wanna try to do this without a module, but for the time being this works a charm.  Well, actually I ended up using Menu Item Visibility module instead since people reported having problems with Menu Per Role on D7.

Answer (score 2):

You might do that with a simple block, rather than creating a menu, preprocess it to add the word between and check if the user is logged in.

Simply select anonymous/authenticated user under the "Roles" in block visibility settings.